# Deleted Emails longer than 90 days

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I need to recover google email that has been deleted more than 90 days.
i would like to use an API to recover the deleted email user. Can you please send me the API and instructions.

Comment: __Please clarify__: What was deleted? What would you like to recover? (email message, email-address, username, account). Which API or programming environment/language would you like to use? And most important: __Share what you tried__, the pseudo-code! And where the actual problem lies? A [example] would be best starting-point to help you.

Answer (score 1):

if is a G Suite user it cannot be restored after 20 days of deletion. Fore more information you can check [Restore a recently deleted user](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1397578?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

as you can read on the following [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7401?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) When you delete a message, it stays in your Trash for 30 days. After that time, it will be permanently deleted from your account and can't be recovered.

The only way to recover this information is if you already have a retention rule on Vault. this is explained on this [link](https://support.google.com/vault/answer/6069193)

Comment: I take it we do not have a vault with our account .. then no way at all it can be restored??

Comment: No, after 30 days is not possible.